# Check Associative 2d Array

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following declaration of array

```
Array
(
    [name] => 1
    [callrate] => 1
    [maxcalls] => 100000
    [mintime] => 5
    [maxtime] => 16
    [skillexps] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
        )
)
```

How can I check the the array contains the array. I tried the

```
function is_multi($a) {
    foreach ($a as $v) {
      if (is_array($v)) 
      {
        return "has array";
        break;
      }
      break;
    }
    return 'only value';
}
```

But this only gives 'only value'. I need to check the If Associative Array is two dimensional.

Comment: I've added an answer you why your code doesn't work and how it'll work. Have a look :) Hope it helps

Answer (score 3):

**Why your existing code doesn't work?**

Because you're looking every element of array to check is it an array or not using `foreach()` and `is_array()`? if not then `break;` so when it checks for `name` element the **value is not an array, it is just a integer** so it immediately `break;` and goes out of the `foreach()`loop and returns **only value** but when I removed the **extra** `break;` from your code it works fine because then it checks for each and every element of your array to verify that is it contains an array or not . I've also added a good looking way how to check array is multi-dimensional or not. Hope this helps :)

```
function is_multi($a) {
    foreach ($a as $v) {
      if (is_array($v)) 
      {
        return "has array";
        break;
      }
      // removed extra break; from here
    }
    return 'only value';
}
```

**To check array is multi-dimensional or not? I'll do this way**,

```
<?php
function is_multi(array $array) {
    return count($array) !== count($array, COUNT_RECURSIVE);
}
$array = array
    (
    'name' => 1,
    'callrate' => 1,
    'maxcalls' => 100000,
    'mintime' => 5,
    'maxtime' => 16,
    'skillexps' => array
    (
        1,
        2
    )
);
echo is_multi($array);
?>
```

**DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/LANsh

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to check whether the array is 2d or not , you can use array filter like below

```
$data=array
(
    'name' => 1,
    'callrate' => 1,
    'maxcalls' => 100000,
    'mintime' => 5,
    'maxtime' => 16,
    'skillexps' =>array(1,2)
);
$filteredItems = array_filter($data, function($elem) {
    return is_array($elem);
});
if(count($filteredItems)>0){
 echo "multi dimensional";
}

else{
 echo "1 dimensional";
}
```

If you are interested to check every keys,you can use array_map with closure function like below

```
$data=array
(
    'name' => 1,
    'callrate' => 1,
    'maxcalls' => 100000,
    'mintime' => 5,
    'maxtime' => 16,
    'skillexps' => array
        (
            0 => 1,
            1 => 2
        )
);

$array = array_map(function ($a) {
            return is_array($a) ? "has array" : "only value";
        }, $data);
print_r($array);
```

output

```
Array
(
    [name] => only value
    [callrate] => only value
    [maxcalls] => only value
    [mintime] => only value
    [maxtime] => only value
    [skillexps] => has array
)
```

If you want to check entire array is multidimensional or not then just add one line below

```
$multi=array_search('has array', $array) ? "is  multi " : "is not multi";
echo $multi;
```

Comment: I tried but the this array also return the same result
Array
(
    [name] => 2
    [maxagents] => 1
    [loginrate] => 2
    [logoutrate] => 1
    [gotobreakrate] => 1
    [returnfrombreakrate] => 1
    [agentidprefix] => sk2ag
    [mintalktime] => 60
    [maxtalktime] => 600
)

Comment: yea, because it has no arrays inside array.